# Loss of energy during harmonic resonance

Tags: energy, resonance, harmonics

I have been trying to determine the function describing how energy is lost during harmonic resonance:

Say an input of energy at the resonant frequency of a closed resonator. I know the following harmonics of the fundamental will be lower in amplitude, but I am unable to figure out how the amount of energy will have been lost at each harmonic.

Apologies if this is too basic.
The system is a Helmholtz Resonator and the energy being applied is at a frequency that is an integer multiple of the resonant frequency. If energy is decaying, the amount of energy input won't be the amount when resonance is actually occurring. The actual resonance frequency is usually around 20 times the frequency being input. That is why I am curious about how much energy has been lost by the time the resonance frequency is hit. More specifically: if the multiple changes to 23, how much more energy would it take initially to equal the same amount when the multiple is 20.

I don't know if this explanation makes more sense in the context of the actual problem. Let me know if I can provide more info.